# Прочитать большой файл не сжирая память

Tags: php

Есть огромный файл коротких строчек (URLов). База где-то на 20 мега байт. Обычный хостер будет бить если я начну при каждом запросе читать файл и отдавать одну случайную строчку из жирного файла.

Как прочитать случайную строчку из огромного файла не сжирая кучу памяти ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$fp     = fopen($filename, 'r');
$offset = mt_rand(0, filesize($filename) - 1);
fseek($fp, $offset);

// пока не встретится перенос строки или начало файла
while ($offset > 0 && fgetc($fp) != "\n") {
    fseek($fp, --$offset);
}

$line = fgets($fp);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$avg_line_len = 30; // Средняя длинна строки
$file = fopen("list-url.txt", "r");
if ($file !== FALSE) {
    $stat = fstat( $file );
    do {
        do {
            $post = rand( 0, $stat['size'] - $avg_line_len );
        } while( fseek($file, $pos) == -1 );
        fgets($file); // Первый раз читаем до первого \n,
                      // так как можем попасть в середину строки
    } while( ($url = fgets($file)) == FALSE);
    // $url - случайная строчка из файла
}
```

P.S.

При большом размере файла (в исходной задаче несколько мегабайт) значением `$avg_line_len` можно пренебречь, а вместо `fstat` использовать `filesize` - результат будет тот-же самый

Comment: 1. Первая строка никогда не попадет в выборку.
2. Если последний URL будет длиннее 30 символов, то большая вероятность получить бесконечный цикл.
3. Функция `rand()` имеет очень низкую энтропию. Рекомендуется использовать `mt_rand()`

Comment: При нулевом размере файла или файле содержащем одну строку так-же получаем бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Идея правильная, реализацию можно подправить. Только сейчас заметил ответ с правкой от @Ilya Pirogov

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю более простое решение. Сам файл нужно разбить на десяток(два) поменьше. Дальше, пусть в начальном файле было 100000 строк, а файлов 100 штук. Даем им имена вида "file00.txt","file01.txt" ... "file99.txt". С помощью rand(0,100); выбираем имя файла, а rand(0,1000); - строку. Дальше - так как приведено в других ответах.

Но главное не сильно увлекаться. 1000 файлов в одном каталоге уже будет подтормаживать. Поэтому нужно экспериментировать. Может будет смысл создать 10 каталогов с именами 0 - 9, и  туда положить по 100 файлов, в каждом по 100 строк.

Если кол-во строк не расскладывается на части оптимально, можно либо дублировать часть строк, либо обрабатывать кол-во строк в файле.

**UPD:**

Родился ещё один вариант, который может дать сильный прирост. Но для этого нужно будет подготовить файл для начала. Алгоритм такой. Проходим по всему файлу, находим самый длинный урл. Зная его длину, делаем новый файл, у которого каждая строка дополнена пробелами до нужной длины. Теперь, что бы перейти к нужной строке, нужно просто сделать [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) - `fseek(номер_строки*(длина_строки) + 1))`. Где 1 - это учет перевода строки (хотя нужно посмотреть, под виндой может быть 2). А после fseek можно читать данные.

Comment: В таком случае, нужно уже запихивать в БД и не мучаться. Таблица 5Гб с линейным поиском для нее не проблема.

Comment: я думал о БД. Но все сильно зависит от задачи. Очень сильно.

Comment: Да тогда-уж проще построить построчный индекс для этого текстового файла, а потом делать выбор случайной строки по-индексу. Вопрос в том насколько часто меняется файл

Comment: @knes, "Таблица 5Гб с линейным поиском для нее не проблема"

Объясните, каким чудом СУБД для неиндесксированных данных обеспечит скорость выше, чем последовательное чтение файла ?

Comment: Кто сказал "неиндексированные данные"? индекс - айдишник. он же - номер строки.
Под линейным поиском подразумевалось отсутствие операций, вроде Join или сравнение ячеек одной таблицы.

Comment: Прочитал по диагонали, в голове есть такая мысль:
Изменять исходный не надо, а вот построить индекс можно, а индекс это просто смещения каждой новой строки, например:

    0,13,24,39,..

Если каждая строка в среднем имеет длину 20 байт, а каждая запись индекса 5-6 байт, то индекс будет в 4 раза меньше базы. Забавно, тогда если база будет 8мг, то индекс будет 2 мегабайта.

Подумаешь подумаешь, идеи конечно очень интересные, но первые варианты с случайным тыком и поиском перевода строки сильно эффективнее.

Comment: Для данного вида фалов (до 2G) проще всего иметь фиксированную длину индекса 4 байта, тогда размер файла индекса будет составлять 4 * кол-во_строк, а выбор случайного смещения:

    $idx_size = filesize($idx_file);
    fseek($idx, mt_rand(0,$idx_size/4)*4);
    list(,$offest) =  unpack("N",fread($idx,4));

Answer (score 1):

```
$rand_line_number = rand(0,1000);
$handle = @fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $i = 0;
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        if($i==$rand_line_number){
            echo $buffer;
            break;
        }
        $i++;

    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Ошибка чтения файла\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Чем это не чтение всего файла?)

Comment: Это чтение всего файла. Но это чтение построчное. Оно единовременно занимает очень немного памяти

Answer (score 1):

Перегони весь этот "огромный" файл в БД, и вытаскивай из БД. Если боишься перегонять это все дело на хосте, сделай на локалке, а потом залей базу на хост.

Comment: Да я думал над этим, и это прекрасный вариант, но у меня нетерпимость к SQLам разным, впрочем как вариант это всегда будет отличным вариантом.

Comment: "но у меня нетерпимость к SQLам разным"

это плохо

Answer (score 1):

```
function fileRandLine($file)
{
    $res = '';

    if (is_file($file)) {
        $filesize = filesize($file);
        if ($filesize > 0) {
            $fp = @fopen($file, 'rt');
            if (is_resource($fp)) {
                for ($i = 0; $str = fgets($fp, $filesize + 1); $i++) {
                    if (mt_rand(0, $i) == 0) {
                        $trim = trim($str);
                        if (empty($trim)) {
                            $i--;
                            continue;
                        }
                        $res = $trim;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Применение:

```
echo fileRandLine('file.txt');
```